# DatabaseError Table doesn't exist for Django and Google Cloud SQL

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

Is there a step that I missed, perhaps a "syncdb" step for Google Cloud SQL? I read both of these:
[Using Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/)

[Django Support](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django)

My application has access to Google Cloud SQL but I think I just have to create the tables in Google Cloud SQL. What's the command to do that? Maybe that will fix it. Running `python manage.py syncdb` updates SQL on localhost but I'd like to update the database on Google Cloud SQl.

EDIT: Below are the Google Cloud SQL settings and the settings.py for my project.
[image: Google Cloud SQL settings]
[image: settings.py]

Comment: Could you show your settings.file and Google configuration? I think you have not set the right database.

Comment: you have to edit your settings so that it uses the remote SQL db rather then the local one them syncdb will update the remote db

Comment: Thanks! How should I change my current settings? I added them to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are three type of connections: 
  1) your dev machine to your local mysql instance (Easy!)
  2) your app engine instance (in Google Cloud) to Google Cloud SQL instance (the same way described in the document)
  3) your dev machine to cloudsql instance (Hard): the encouraged way is to obtain an static IP (for a while that doesn't cost you much money), and use the IP to connect cloudsql instance.

Django code [3] should allow you switch between above cases. The command [1] allows you to syncdb to cloudsql instance. If you want your django model to manipulate data in cloudsql instance, you can add config [2] to app.yaml

[1]

```
SETTING_MODE=prod ./manage.py syncdb
```

[2]

```
env_variables:
  SETTINGS_MODE: prod
```

[3]

```
import os
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    # Running on production App Engine, so use a Google Cloud SQL database.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/your-project-id:your-instance-name',
            'NAME': 'django_test',
            'USER': 'root',
        }
    }
elif os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODE') == 'prod':
    # Running in development, but want to access the Google Cloud SQL instance
    # in production.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': 'static-ip-of-cloudsql-instance',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'NAME': 'django_test',
            'USER': 'username',
            'PASSWORD': 'password'
        }
    }
else:
    # Running in development, so use a local MySQL database.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'django_test',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': 'root',
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do I use the [1] command? Via command prompt in the folder? Also, that's a Linux command :p I can translate to Windows but still.

Comment: Update: I added the env_variable to app.yaml but it still does syncdb to localhost. I also don't know the conversion of the [1] command to Windows apparently because doing `python SETTINGS_MODE=prod manage.py syncdb` doesn't work.